# Perron's formula (Passing a limit under the integral)

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I want to understand why assuming that $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ converges uniformly for $\mathrm{Re}(s) > \sigma > 0$ with $c > \sigma$ implies that
$$
\sum_{n \le x} \, \!\!^* a_n = \frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \sum_{n \ge 1}  \frac{a_n}{n^s} \frac{x^s}{s} \, ds. 
$$
I've managed to show that for $c > 0$,
$$
\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i \infty}^{c + i \infty} \frac{y^s}s \, ds = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } 0 < y < 1 \\
1/2 & \text{ if } y = 1 \\
1 & \text{ if } y > 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
so we can write
$$
\sum_{n \le x} \, \!\!^* a_n = \frac 1{2\pi i} \sum_{n \ge 1} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} a_n \left( \frac xn \right)^s \frac{ds}s \overset{!}{=} \frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^s} \frac{x^s}s \, ds.
$$
But that $!$ that I put there means I don't understand why the sum can go under the integral sign. Any ideas about that part? Thanks.

Comment: I must say that $$\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i \infty}^{c + i \infty} \frac{y^s}s \, ds$$ doesn't not converge for $y=1$, but his Cauchy principal value $$\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i T}^{c + i T} \frac{y^s}s \, ds$$ exist and it's equal to $1/2$.

You can find [here](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~djankovic/Peronova_formula.pdf) detail version of proof, but there is small problem: it is on Serbian, but there is a lot formula so you should made it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even the basic identity, about integrating $y^s/s$ on a vertical line, requires qualification to be truly sensible, since the integral is certainly not absolutely convergent. One way to be completely up-front about it is to compute $\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT} {y^s\over s}\,ds$ and keep track of the error (from the ideal answers you give) in terms of $y$ and $T$. A finite-extent integral *can* certainly be interchanged with the sum over $n$. Then summing the Dirichlet series gives an estimable error, which goes to $0$ as $T$ goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: So you're saying I should just re-work out the proof I did for the integral $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i \infty}$ y^s/s \, ds$ and keep track of the error when I'm summing? I thought it would be more easy than that, I was too lazy to try it that way. This approach does seem hard though.

Comment: Yes, probably you should just redo the intuitive version more scrupulously. Yes, it requires some labor, but it's not profoundly difficult. That it requires _something_ is not unreasonable, given the not-absolute-convergence. In some scenarios, integrating against $y^s/s(s-1)(s-2)...(s-\ell)$ with $\ell\ge1$ is sufficient, and _does_ give better convergence. But, in fact, often this more-smoothed "sample" gives substantially-less-interesting results, unfortunately. Thus, all the more with hindsight, the trouble it takes to be sure of the simpler-but-not-absolutely-convergent case is warranted.

Comment: Um, you seem to put $y^2$ all the time, I meant $y^s$, you know that right? Or is it just a frequent typo of yours :P

Comment: Heh... "2" or "s"... kinda similar? :)

Comment: So should I try to bound
$$
\left| \int_{c-iT}^{c+iT} \sum_{ n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^s} \frac{x^s}s \, ds - \sum_{n \le x} \,\!\!^* a_n \right| 
$$
by some function of $T$ that goes to zero as $T$ goes to infinity?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about a few details, but I'm pretty sure I can work them out... after my exam tomorrow! Thanks paul. =D